# IndexOutOfBoundsException when I attempt to use list.contain(...), not sure how to fix

Tags: java-8, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    List<String> stuff = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> fc = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> on = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> done = new ArrayList<String>();

    int d=0;
    int x=0;
    int r=0;

    //"inputs" is an array with all the inputs from the user.  
    //You will have to go through and extract the data from "inputs" and store it in     
    //a data type that works
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputs_size = 0;
    inputs_size = 100;

    String[] inputs = new String[inputs_size];
    for(int i = 0; i < inputs_size; i++) {
        String inputs_item;
        try {
            inputs_item = in.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            inputs_item = null;
        }
        inputs[i] = inputs_item;
    }

    for(int n=0; n<inputs.length-1; n++){
        if(inputs[n]==null){
            break;
        }
        stuff.add(inputs[n]);
    }

    while(d<stuff.size()){
        if(stuff.get(d).equals("0")){
              x++;
        }
        d++;
    }

    for(int t=0; t<stuff.size(); t++){
        if(stuff.get(t).equals("0")){
            break;
        }
        fc.add(stuff.get(t));
    }

    r=fc.size();

    while(r<stuff.size()-1){
        if(stuff.get(r).equals("0")){
            r++;
            x=x-1;
        }

        if(x==4 && stuff.get(r)!="0"){
            on.add(stuff.get(r));
        }
        if(x==3 && stuff.get(r)!="0"){
            tw.add(stuff.get(r));
        }
        if(x==2 && stuff.get(r)!="0"){
            th.add(stuff.get(r));
        }
        if(x==1 && stuff.get(r)!="0"){
            fo.add(stuff.get(r));
        }
        if(x==0 && stuff.get(r)!="0"){
            fi.add(stuff.get(r));
        }
        if(x==-1 && stuff.get(r)!="0"){
            si.add(stuff.get(r));
        }
        r++;
    }

    int z=0;
    int counter = 1;
    for(; counter < fc.size(); counter++) {
        if(counter>fc.size()){
            break;
        }

        **if(fc.contains(on.get(counter)))** {
            z=0;
        }
        else{
            z=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(z==0){
        done.add(on.get(0));
    }
    counter=1;
    z=0;

    System.out.println(done);

    }
}
```

I am getting an IndexOutOfBounds error for the line of code with the asterisks around it (fc.contains(...)). I am attempting to create a program that acts as a fridge, receives input and determines what recipes I am capable of making.

Example input:
(milk
cheese
eggs
honey)           -ingredients in fridge
(0)              -separates lists
(eggs and honey) -recipe in question
(eggs
honey)           -ingredients required for recipe, are they in fridge?? yes

So my output would be: Eggs and Honey, or the names of the recipes I can make.

Where did I go wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Your counter goes from 1 to `fc.size()`. Why would you expect `on` (i.e. another collection) to have at least as many elements as `fc` ?

Comment: On another note, I'm not sure you really understand what you've wrote. Aren't you mistaking `break` for `continue`, and do you realize that `for(int n=0; n<inputs.length-1;n++)` will loop until the penultimate element and NOT consider the last one ? All in all, you're using a lot of collections with really questionable names to somehow increase counters in loops that probably won't cover all elements. It's at the same time really difficult to understand what you're trying to do and looking like you're not doing what you intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

Following your code, I think your `on` array is null.

Look:

```
if(x==4 && stuff.get(r)!="0"){
  on.add(stuff.get(r));
}
```

It is the only time you try to add something to your `on`. And your `fc` and `stuff` size will be the same, since you doesn't have something to make it different (instead of this `.equals("0")`, but if you enter anything else, it will be the same). After that, we have:

```
r=fc.size();

while(r<stuff.size()-1){
```

We know that `fc` and `stuff` have the same size, then `r` won't be lower than `stuff.size()-1`.
By not entering the loop, it will remains null. So any `.get()` will result in `IndexOutOfBounds`.